# In prestashop while implementing paypal integration i am getting following error

Tags: prestashop

I am new to prestashop. while implementing paypal integration module i am getting following error as

```
Please try to contact the merchant:

PayPal response:
TIMESTAMP -> 2013-08-13T10:15:35Z
L_ERRORCODE0 -> 10002
L_SHORTMESSAGE0 -> Security error
L_LONGMESSAGE0 -> Security header is not valid
L_SEVERITYCODE0 -> Error
```

Please anyone help on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/store/order/paypal/paypal-53.html

Answer (score 1):

this error always occurs when you enter bad credentials.
Just check your credentials and everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used the credentials which was provided by Paypal. If it is bad credentials where i have to concentrate to overcome this issue. Please suggest

Comment: If you copy/paste your credentials check that you don't have a white space at the end. After having configured many PayPal's modules I've always seen this error when the merchant was using bad credential. You should double check your credentials.